# Нужно добавить врагу радиус возможной атаки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно, чтобы когда я приближался на какое-то определенное расстояние к врагу, я мог бы его убить (как в Among us, например, если ты входишь в возможный радиус, то кнопка подсвечивается и ты можешь убить), но как это лучше сделать?

У меня есть вариант добавить и привязать к врагу круг и через OnTriggerStay сделать так, что в радиусе этого круга его можно убить, но будет ли это корректно, и как лучше сделать?

Comment: Так и делай и если несколько целей в радиусе, то добавляй их в список и высчитывай расстояние до каждого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Врагу добавьте поле `float attackDistance` - это радиус атаки. Допустим, у вас есть объект игрока и объект соперника. Тогда вы делаете проверку на расстояние между ними с помощью функции [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html):

```
private void Update () {
  if (Vector3.distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position) < attackDistance)
  {
    // Делаем, что хотим
  }
```

Проверять каждый кадр необязательно, тоn же Among us, там вряд ли нужно это делать. Можно проверять раз 10 в секунду, или вообще 5. Разницы не особо: проверять 10 раз в секунду (каждые 0.1) или проверять каждый кадр, т.е. 60 раз в секунду (каждые 0.017) при ФПС = 60.

Ваш вариант тоже неплох, особенно если противников несколько, причем нет 1 цели и реагировать нужно одинаково на всех, но тогда вам нужно 2 скрипта: один на круг с кодом:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter () { 
  // Вызываем метод OnEnemySeen() в игроке
}
```

А в игроке пишем другой скрипт с кодом:

```
public void OnEnemySeen() {
  // Делаем что-то
}
```

> P.S. Пожалуйста, если вы пишите про игру, пишите ее правильно. Ладно, пусть люди, которые делают мемчики по игре пишут Amoung Us (я видел такое), но судя по тому, что вы вообще есть на этом сайте, вы увлекаетесь программированием, вы вполне умный человек и можете писать правильно: Among Us. Потому что с англ. Among - между (причем между больше, чем двумя, если между двумя, то between). В английском языке В ПРИНЦИПЕ нет слова Amoung.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ
И да, за Amoung Us извиняюсь)

Comment: @MAXEMGAAA пожалуйста